# Trying to delete a member from the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I am having some trouble trying to delete a member from the database I'm using, I don't think it is getting the Username correctly. Here is the form I am using for HTML

## deleteForm.php

```
<?php
    //begin our session
    session_start();
?>
    <html> 
        <head> 
            <title>Welcome</title> 
        </head> 
            <form action="deleteUser.php">
               <p>
                   <center><label for="Username">Enter username to delete</center></label> 
                   <center><input type="text" id="Username" name="Username" value="" maxlength="20" /></center>
                   <center><input type="submit" value="Delete Member"></center>
               </p> 
            </form>
        </body> 
    </html>
```

And this is the code to handle the deletion itself:

## deleteUser.php

```
<?php
//begin our session
session_start();

//Check if username, password have been sent
if((!filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Username')))
{
    echo 'Please enter a valid username';
}
else
{
    //Enter the valid data into the database
    $memberUsername = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    
    echo $memberUsername;
    
    $SQLhostname = "****";
    $SQLusername = "****";
    $SQLpassword = "****";
    $databaseName = "****";
    
    try
    {
      echo "in the try block";
        // Create connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect($SQLhostname, $SQLusername, $SQLpassword)
                or die("Unable to connect MySQL");

        $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($conn, $databaseName)
            or die("Could not select database");

        $deleteMember = "DELETE FROM customers
                        WHERE name = 
                        '$memberUsername'";

        $result = $conn->query($deleteMember);

        if(! $result ){
            die('Could not delete member: ' . $conn->error);}
        else{
            echo "Member deleted <br/>";
        }
        
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) 
    {
       //To be added

    }
}
?>
```

The problem is it always enters the if statement and asks for a valid username which I'm assuming is not being set.

Comment: Since a method is omitted in your form, it defaults to GET and you're using `INPUT_POST` that should be `INPUT_GET` or add a post method, i.e: `method="post"`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: That was it, thanks for the help, id give you an up vote but I've not enough cred

Comment: You're welcome. I always like to put in a comment first to make 100% sure. Many a time, it's a mix of other issues. I have lived and learned here on Stack ;) I'll make my comment an answer if you can upvote it. Just say the word.

Comment: No worries, ha i've a long way to go compared to your reputation :P I just earned enough there, upvote given!

Comment: I'm always glad to help out Jay, and to share the wealth "as it were", *cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `method` attribute to your `form`.

```
<form action="deleteUser.php" method="post">
                            <!--^^^^^^^^^^-->
    <p>
        <center><label for="Username">Enter username to delete</center></label>
        <center><input type="text" id="Username" name="Username" value="" maxlength="20" /></center>
        <center><input type="submit" value="Delete Member"></center>
    </p>
```

Comment: That was it, thanks for your help, ill select your answer when I can

Answer (score 1):

Just as a quick FYI:

Whenever a method is omitted in a form, it defaults to GET and you're using `INPUT_POST` therefore you should either be using `INPUT_GET` or add a post method, i.e: `method="post"`.

Consult the manual:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php**

Plus, and for your added safety, your code is open SQL injection. Do [**use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Answer (score 0):

in the form tag add "method" attribute:

```
<form ... method="POST">
```

In the PHP script you van find the value of inputs in the variable $_GET:

$_GET[Username'']

Kevin